# Do ajax call and jquery from server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a script that makes an ajax call to yahoo API which then 'crawls' a given URL and sent back the data. Second the data is being send to a service called "Embedly" (which is another call) The embedly service then does its thing and sens back the data which is showed as plain HTML. Please look at the script, its very simple: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/149/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    baseUrl = "http://www.nu.nl";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "",
        success: function(data) {

            $foop = $('<form>' + data.responseText + '</form>');
            console.log(data.responseText);

            $.each($foop.find('h3 a[href]'), function(idx, item) {
                lnk = $(item).attr("href");
                 text = ('http://www.nu.nl');

$('<fb:like href="' + text + lnk + '"></fb:like><a href="' + text + lnk + '"></a>').appendTo('#content');
});


 $('div#content').embedly({key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 words: 10
 }); 

        },
        error: function(status) {
            //console.log("request error:"+url);
        }
    });


    });
```

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes it takes to long to make the calls, especially in the evening and weekends the yahoo API and embedly really take a long time to return data. I would like to solve this problem by making the calls server side with PHP. So that if a visitor visits my site he would receive data from my server instead. Of course the data would have to be 'refreshed' somehow for instance every minute or so. I have googled for this but I cant seem to find anything which describes ajax call with PHP and so on.

Comment: May be you want to remove your embedly key from the code!

Comment: @check123 Not really an issue, I'm still using a free version

Comment: alternatively you could set an longer timeout: in you ajax param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is create a server side proxy, create a file and name it YahooAPIProxy.php` inside this file call the yahoo API like

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');
function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
}

    $url = “http://www.nu.nl”;
    $str = file_get_contents($url);

    echo $str;
?>
```

call this proxy from the client side like

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '/YahooAPIProxy.php',
        type: "get",           
        dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data) {
            $foop = $('<form>' + data.responseText + '</form>');
            console.log(data.responseText);

            $.each($foop.find('h3 a[href]'), function(idx, item) {
                lnk = $(item).attr("href");
                 text = ('http://www.nu.nl');

$('<fb:like href="' + text + lnk + '"></fb:like><a href="' + text + lnk + '"></a>').appendTo('#content');
});
```

similarly you can repeat the procedure for the Embedly API

Comment: Wow incredible:) Thanks a lot. I still have to test this but if it works it could save me a lot of headache. (I don't know anything of PHP)

Comment: Hi again, can you please help me out..? It doesn't work for me..I think I might have misunderstood the part that says `http://www.YOUR_API_URL.com` What do you mean by that? Do you mean the url which is baseUrl in my example above??(Because I don't see it anyware in your code...) Or do you mean the url of the script at github???

Comment: @Youss by `your_api_url` i meant the address of the API which you call to get the data, yes the `baseURL` in your code

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please take a look at my example code again. The baseUrl is not an API, it is in fact a Dutch news website...The API call is a script from github, If you take a look at the JsFiddle example you will see I added it like so `<script src='https://raw.github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js'></script>` The problem is that your code doesn't cover the Dutch news website(baseUrl) which is http://nu.nl/ Its nowhere in your code so the call is empty..

Comment: i have edited the answer to include the news website, my bad for using the api jargon, i thing the script from the github is only to over come the cross origin resource sharing limitation, with the example i have provided in the answer you probably dont need the github script because you are not calling the news website from the client i.e. browser instead the news website will be called from the server proxy (YahooAPIProxy.php) make sure that you have placed the php at the server root

Comment: Please take a look at my website: http://moskah.nl/indexmet.html As you can see it is a blank page. To bad..(Thanks for the effort though)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18882/discussion-between-3nigma-and-youss)

Comment: i have again edited the answer add the header information and the proper char set

Comment: Thanks for sticking around, it doesnt work for me. Im going to sleep, I will look at it tommorow

Answer (score 3):

Basically ajax calls are just HTTP-GET-calls. Just use curl (recommended) or `file_get_contents()` with php.

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php you have the equivalent in post if needed...